# Layer from DragBox selection - openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there a way to create a new layer from a DragBox selection?

Here is my DragBox interaction:

```
/* create drag box */
this.dragBox = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
    /* dragbox interaction is active only if alt key is pressed */
    condition: ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly,
    /* style the box */
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: [0, 0, 255, 1]
        })
    })
});
/* add the DragBox interaction to the map */
this.map.addInteraction(this.dragBox);
```

On the boxend event I want to create a new layer using the data in my bounding box. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is fairly straightforward approach.

1. You can get your boundary (in openlayer's term is called 'extent') like this:

   ```
    var extent = this.dragBox.getGeometry().getExtent(); // you can use this inside the boxend event
   ```
2. With this boundary, you can filter the map with whatever method you want. For example using openlayers geometry intersect, to check which feature in the layer that intersects the extent:

   ```
   var isIntersect=feature.getGeometry().intersectsExtent(extent);
   ```
3. Then create a layer and populate it with the features you filtered.